# FileTransfer DWR and input file MULTIPLE. Uploading files

Tags: java, ajax, file, upload, dwr

my problem: I use `DWR3` (FileTransfer) for upload files from `jsp` without any problem, but now we want to use the file in `MULTIPLE` mode, this is:

```
input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="... (HTML5)
```

this avoid to the typical dialog for searching files to select more than one file of the client system. But, How I catch them in the server?

I attempt without success:

```
public String catchMultipleFiles(FileTransfer[] files, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{ ...}
public String catchMultipleFiles(ArrayList<FileTransfer> files, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{ ...}
```

Always my older version for catch one works perfectly, simply:

```
public String catchOneFile(FileTransfer file, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{ ...}
```

Anyone have this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the logs?

Comment: The log for the FileTransfer[] option (array):

Comment: Put it in an answer...